# "Set the REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL environment variable" when trying to run django server

Tags: python, django, server, .env

I was given a directory with Django project, and my task is to fing out hot it works. Cause I'm just statrting to study Django I face some difficulties with it. When I try to run server this error message occurs

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py:275, in Env.get_value(self, var, cast, default, parse_default)
    274 try:
--> 275     value = self.ENVIRON[var]
    276 except KeyError:

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py:679, in _Environ.__getitem__(self, key)
    677 except KeyError:
    678     # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 679     raise KeyError(key) from None
    680 return self.decodevalue(value)

KeyError: 'REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImproperlyConfigured                      Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\xok4ge\Documents\VS Code\kycbase\backend\manage.py in line 22
     18     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     21 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 22     main()

c:\Users\xok4ge\Documents\VS Code\kycbase\backend\manage.py in line 18, in main()
     12 except ImportError as exc:
     13     raise ImportError(
     14         "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
     15         "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
     16         "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
     17     ) from exc
---> 18 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:442, in execute_from_command_line(argv)
    440 """Run a ManagementUtility."""
    441 utility = ManagementUtility(argv)
--> 442 utility.execute()

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:436, in ManagementUtility.execute(self)
    434     sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + "\n")
    435 else:
--> 436     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:262, in ManagementUtility.fetch_command(self, subcommand)
    256 except KeyError:
    257     if os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"):
    258         # If `subcommand` is missing due to misconfigured settings, the
    259         # following line will retrigger an ImproperlyConfigured exception
    260         # (get_commands() swallows the original one) so the user is
    261         # informed about it.
--> 262         settings.INSTALLED_APPS
    263     elif not settings.configured:
    264         sys.stderr.write("No Django settings specified.\n")

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py:102, in LazySettings.__getattr__(self, name)
    100 """Return the value of a setting and cache it in self.__dict__."""
    101 if (_wrapped := self._wrapped) is empty:
--> 102     self._setup(name)
    103     _wrapped = self._wrapped
    104 val = getattr(_wrapped, name)

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py:89, in LazySettings._setup(self, name)
     81     desc = ("setting %s" % name) if name else "settings"
     82     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
     83         "Requested %s, but settings are not configured. "
     84         "You must either define the environment variable %s "
     85         "or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."
     86         % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
     87     )
---> 89 self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py:217, in Settings.__init__(self, settings_module)
    214 # store the settings module in case someone later cares
    215 self.SETTINGS_MODULE = settings_module
--> 217 mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    219 tuple_settings = (
    220     "ALLOWED_HOSTS",
    221     "INSTALLED_APPS",
   (..)
    224     "SECRET_KEY_FALLBACKS",
    225 )
    226 self._explicit_settings = set()

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127, in import_module(name, package)
    125             break
    126         level += 1
--> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1030, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:850, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File c:\Users\xok4ge\Documents\VS Code\kycbase\backend\zurich1\settings.py:328
    325 SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = 'zurich1.debug_toolbar.show_toolbar'
    326 CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
--> 328 REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL = env('REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL')

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py:125, in Env.__call__(self, var, cast, default, parse_default)
    124 def __call__(self, var, cast=None, default=NOTSET, parse_default=False):
--> 125     return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default)

File c:\Users\xok4ge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py:279, in Env.get_value(self, var, cast, default, parse_default)
    277     if default is self.NOTSET:
    278         error_msg = "Set the {0} environment variable".format(var)
--> 279         raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
    281     value = default
    283 # Resolve any proxied values

ImproperlyConfigured: Set the REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL environment variable
```

I haven't found any info about this variable, and in **settings.py** there is only one line mentions it

```py
REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL = env('REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL')
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem and searching in web doesnt give any results

There is how **setup_env.sh** looks like

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export ENV_FILE=".env.prod"

echo LOCALHOST=localhost >>$ENV_FILE

echo DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=$DJANGO_SECRET_KEY>>$ENV_FILE
echo DJANGO_MODE=$DJANGO_MODE>>$ENV_FILE
echo DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=$DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS>>$ENV_FILE
echo DJANGO_SSL=$DJANGO_SSL>>$ENV_FILE
echo DJANGO_DOMAIN=$DJANGO_DOMAIN>>$ENV_FILE
echo DJANGO_INTERNAL_IPS=>>$ENV_FILE

echo EMAIL_HOST=$EMAIL_HOST>>$ENV_FILE
echo EMAIL_PORT=$EMAIL_PORT>>$ENV_FILE
echo EMAIL_USER=$EMAIL_USER>>$ENV_FILE
echo EMAIL_PASSWORD=$EMAIL_PASSWORD>>$ENV_FILE
echo EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=$EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS>>$ENV_FILE

echo POSTGRES_NAME=$POSTGRES_NAME>>$ENV_FILE
echo POSTGRES_PORT=$POSTGRES_PORT>>$ENV_FILE
echo POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER>>$ENV_FILE
echo POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD>>$ENV_FILE

echo SENTRY_DSN=$SENTRY_DSN>>$ENV_FILE

echo STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=$STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY>>$ENV_FILE
echo STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY=$STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY>>$ENV_FILE
echo STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY=$STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY>>$ENV_FILE
echo STRIPE_LIVE_MODE=$STRIPE_LIVE_MODE>>$ENV_FILE
echo STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET=STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET>>$ENV_FILE

echo PHRASE_ACCESS_TOKEN=$PHRASE_ACCESS_TOKEN>>$ENV_FILE
```

A bit of setting up **settings.py**

```py
import mimetypes
import os
from configparser import ConfigParser, RawConfigParser
from pathlib import Path

import debug_toolbar
import sentry_sdk
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from environ import environ

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT_DIR = BASE_DIR.parent
BUILD_DIR = PROJECT_DIR / 'build'


env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DJANGO_MODE=(str, 'production')
)

environ.Env.read_env((PROJECT_DIR / '.env.dev').as_posix())

# SECRET_KEY = config.get('DEFAULT', 'SECRET_KEY')
# SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', default=get_random_secret_key())

# DEBUG = config.get('DEFAULT', 'mode') == 'development'
# DEBUG = int(os.environ.get('DEBUG', default=0))
DEBUG = env('DJANGO_MODE') == 'development'

DOMAIN = env('DJANGO_DOMAIN', default=None)
SSL = env('DJANGO_SSL', default=None) == 'true'

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https') if SSL else None
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = SSL
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = SSL

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = config.get('DEFAULT', 'ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(',')
# ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(";")
ALLOWED_HOSTS = env('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', default='').split(';')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.custom_user',
    'apps.persons',
    'apps.applications',
    'apps.utils',
    'apps.email_verification',
    'apps.dbloader',
    'apps.parsers',
    'apps.welcome',
    'apps.search',
    'apps.graph',
    'apps.articles',
    'apps.personal_area',
    'apps.subscriptions',
    'apps.payments',

    'core.elastic',
    'core.postgres_composite_types',

    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',

    'modeltranslation',
    'rest_framework',

    'django_extensions',
    'django_filters',
    'manifest_loader',

    'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'zurich1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'apps.utils.context_processor.utils',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
                (
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
                ),
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'zurich1.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env('POSTGRES_NAME', default=None),
        'USER': env('POSTGRES_USER', default=None),
        'PASSWORD': env('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', default=None),
        'HOST': env('POSTGRES_HOST', default=None),
        'PORT': env('POSTGRES_PORT', default=0),
        'OPTIONS': {}
    },
}

ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST', default=None),
        'timeout': 120,

    },
}
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'core.elastic.signal_processors.RealTimeSignalProcessor'

CELERY_BROKER_URL = env('CELERY_BROKER_URL', default=None)
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = env('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', default=None)

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.CustomUser'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_TZ = True

# STATIC

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    PROJECT_DIR / "static",
]
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR / "dist"

MANIFEST_LOADER = {
    'manifest_file': BUILD_DIR / 'manifest.json',  # name of your manifest file
}
#

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

EMAIL_MULTI_USER = True  # optional (defaults to False)

# For Django Email Backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = PROJECT_DIR / 'emails'
EMAIL_HOST = env('EMAIL_HOST', default=None)
EMAIL_PORT = int(env('EMAIL_PORT', default=0))
EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = env('EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', default=None)

EMAIL_PAGE_DOMAIN = DOMAIN
EMAIL_PAGE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_USER', default=None)
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_PASSWORD', default=None)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = [
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
]

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = [
    'ru', 'en', 'uk'
]
MODELTRANSLATION_FALLBACK_LANGUAGES = {
    'default': ('en', 'ru'),
    'uk': ('ru',),
    'ru': ('en',)
}

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'locale',
]

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%d.%m.%Y',  # 25.10.2005
    '%Y-%m-%d',  # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y',  # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y',  # '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y',  # 'Oct 25 2006'
    '%b %d, %Y',  # 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y',  # '25 Oct 2006'
    '%d %b, %Y',  # '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y',  # 'October 25 2006'
    '%B %d, %Y',  # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y',  # '25 October 2006'
    '%d %B, %Y',  # '25 October, 2006'
]

ADMIN_TOOLS_MENU = 'menu.CustomMenu'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    },

}

if env('SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT', default=None) != 'local':
    sentry_sdk.init(
        dsn=env('SENTRY_DSN', default=None),
        environment=env('SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT', default=None),
        traces_sample_rate=0.001,

    )

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}

# STRIPE #
STRIPE_LIVE_MODE = env('STRIPE_LIVE_MODE', default=None) == 'production'
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = env('STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY', default=None)
STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY = env('STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY', default=None)
STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY = env('STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY', default=None)
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET = env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET', default=None)
STRIPE_USE_NATIVE_JSONFIELD = True
STRIPE_FOREIGN_KEY_TO_FIELD = "id"

if STRIPE_LIVE_MODE:  # LIVE
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY

else:
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY


if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS += [
        'debug_toolbar',
    ]
MIDDLEWARE += [
    'django_cprofile_middleware.middleware.ProfilerMiddleware',  # cProfile
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]
DJANGO_CPROFILE_MIDDLEWARE_REQUIRE_STAFF = False

INTERNAL_IPS = env('DJANGO_INTERNAL_IPS', default='').split(',')

# this is the main reason for not showing up the toolbar

mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    'DISABLE_PANELS': {
        'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    },
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'zurich1.debug_toolbar.show_toolbar'

}

SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = 'zurich1.debug_toolbar.show_toolbar'
CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True

REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL = env('REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL')
```

And the structure of the project

[image: screenshot]

If this info isn't enough I can post more.
So, the question is how to fix this error

Comment: From the traceback it looks like `backend\zurich1\settings.py` has more settings than you've posted. The error happens on line 328.

Comment: @Selcuk I have updated block with **settings.py**, the error is in line where we try to assign a value to REMOTE_MONITORING_BASE_URL